# leer variable dentro de una funcion anonima en laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

```
 $info = $request->filtro;

    $permisions = Permision::join('users', function ($join) {
                    $join->on('permisions.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
                        ->where('users.id', '=', $info);
                })
                ->simplePaginate(5);
```

Buenas, mi pregunta consiste, en como puedo lograr que la variable info sea leida dentro de la funcion que esta siendo pasada como parametro en join,ya que me imagino que no se ha de poder por el ambito de la variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para heredar variables utiliza `use()`. Ver documentación PHP: http://php.net/manual/es/functions.anonymous.php

```
$permisions = Permision::join('users', function ($join) use ($info) {
                $join->on('permisions.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
                    ->where('users.id', '=', $info);
            })
            ->simplePaginate(5);
```